# (oracle.jbo.JboException) JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: java.lang.NullPointerException, msg=null

Tags: nullpointerexception, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper to create ADF and with one form I have this error:

```
(oracle.jbo.JboException) JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: java.lang.NullPointerException, msg=null
```

Details are:

```
(oracle.jbo.JboException) JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: java.lang.NullPointerException, msg=null
----- LEVEL 1: DETAIL 0 -----
(java.lang.NullPointerException) null
```

Stack trace is:

```
oracle.jbo.JboException: JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: java.lang.NullPointerException, msg=null
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.reportException(DCBindingContainer.java:228)
    at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCBindingContainer.reportException(DCBindingContainer.java:274)
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.setBindingContext(FormOperativniPlan.java:187)
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.main(FormOperativniPlan.java:98)
## Detail 0 ##
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.jbInit(FormOperativniPlan.java:59)
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.setBindingContext(FormOperativniPlan.java:184)
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.main(FormOperativniPlan.java:98)

----- LEVEL 1: DETAIL 0 -----
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.jbInit(FormOperativniPlan.java:59)
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.setBindingContext(FormOperativniPlan.java:184)
    at gui.operativniPlan.FormOperativniPlan.main(FormOperativniPlan.java:98)
```

Any idea where should I look for a problem?

Comment: There's simply not enough information to go on here.  A NPE is one of the most common and obscure Java exceptions.  You would be better off giving details about your application and code.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes I have recieved exceptions as this and most times were launched because I had created a ViewObjectImplementation and had created or edited a method in them that could generate an exception that isn't catch and thus, ADF cant write the error trace .

Thus, mi advise is, if you have some ADF clases Implementation, review it and surround by some try - catch.

Marcos.

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly caused by SQL error or coding error in your java method. If you are exposing your custom business logic in app module make sure the method you are creating in appmoduleimpl is correct. While using findViewObject method, you have to pass view object instance and not the actual view object('VOI' instead of 'VO') as a string.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Since there is a NullPointerException, the probability that a SQL error is involved is rather low.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add Java Options  -Duser.timezone=+6:00 and it will work.

Comment: How can you possibly tell that from the OP?